# Jquery script to show/hide content with the_ID?

Tags: wordpress, hide, show

I have a HTML code:

```
<div class="content">
 blablabla
</div>

<a href="#" class="show">Show hidden content</a>

<a href="#" class="hide">Hide content</a>
```

I need Jquery code to show or hide div "content", but i need that code to work with `<?php the_ID (); ?>` its will be used in posts loop so i need unicue ID's.

Ex.: `<div class="content-<?php the_ID (); ?>">`

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have just one div per $the_ID I think it would be better to use `<div id="<?= $the_ID ?>"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.show').click( function(){
    $('.content-<?php the_ID (); ?>').show();
});

$('.hide').click( function(){
    $('.content-<?php the_ID (); ?>').hide();
});
```